# Why nothing is display when I use QWebpage

Tags: qt, qwebpage

it's very stupid question but I don't understand why nothing is display in my qt console application when I use `QWebpage`  :

This is my basic code :

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QtWebKitWidgets>
#include <QDebug>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    /*QWebPage page;
    page.settings()->setAttribute(QWebSettings::LocalStorageEnabled, true);
    page.settings()->setAttribute(QWebSettings::AutoLoadImages, true);
    page.settings()->setAttribute(QWebSettings::JavascriptEnabled, true);
    page.settings()->setAttribute(QWebSettings::PrintElementBackgrounds, true);
    page.settings()->setAttribute(QWebSettings::PluginsEnabled, true);
    page.mainFrame()->load(QUrl("http://myflowerpower.parrot.com/#plantdb/3"));
    qDebug () << "source html : \n";
    qDebug() << page.currentFrame()->toHtml();
    QString htmlResult = page.currentFrame()->toHtml();*/

    printf("test");
    std::cout << "test std::cout\n";
    qDebug() << "Debug Message";
    qWarning() << "Warning Message";
    qCritical() << "Critical Error Message";
    bool result = a.exec();

    return result;
}
```

If I uncomment the code, nothing is display, but if I comment QWebpage stuff it's work without problem. Have any idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`QCoreApplication` can't handle GUI elements.

You need to use `QApplication` instead to support the GUI and the event framework.

And make sure that you have what is needed in your `.pro` file.

```
QT += widgets webkitwidgets
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: It's work !  QtCreator sucks, I have create a new "console application" and the minimum code generated use `QCoreApplication` instead of `QApplication`